# Insert multiples table rows into a document with google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, tablerow

I developed this code to allow myself to append several rows to a table under the table row that the cursor is inside of.

```
var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
var answer = DocumentApp.getUi().prompt("Add Rows", "Insert the number of rows you want to add in the box below.\nMake sure you have your cursor placed in the table you want to append the rows to.",     DocumentApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
if(answer.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK)
{
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var pos = doc.getCursor();
  var elementin = pos.getElement();
  var tablecell = elementin.getParent();
  var tablerow = tablecell.getParent();
  var table = tablerow.getParent();

  for(var i = 0; i < answer.getResponseText(); i++)
      {
        var row = table.asTable().insertTableRow(table.getChildIndex(tablerow)+1);
        for(var j = 0; j < tablerow.getNumChildren(); j++)
            {
              row.insertTableCell(0);
            }
      }
}
doc.saveAndClose();
```

The code executes fine, but when I try to highlight rows that were originally created by the default Google table building function `Table\Insert Table→` and rows appended from this program, the page freezes and I get the error message of

> File unavailable
>   Sorry, there's a problem with this file. Please reload.
>
> If this keeps happening, you can report the error.

I assume that this program is editing the table incorrectly. The table displays correct, but when attempting to highlight original rows and the new rows at the same time, everything freezes.

Comment: Tried the code snippet provided and it works fine for me. How did you create the initial table in the doc? through the Doc ui or through a different apps script function?

Comment: I created the table manually without the script. I just hovered over the table creator and selected the rows and columns. Like jjjjoe said, my file is probably just corrupted and that the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with KRR above; there's nothing wrong with your snippet. There's likely something corrupt about your document, and you simply need to use a new one.

You should be able to simply make a copy of the document (File -> Make a copy...) and then copy/paste the script into the new document. If the problem follows you to the new doc, then you'll have to copy/paste the entire content into a document you've created from scratch (via the "+" button on docs.google.com)